# Monkey Patching jQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery

I am looking to replace jQuery's existing `$.ajax` call with a custom wrapper. The closest I can get is

```
(function ($) {

    var internalAjax = $.ajax;

    function getAccessToken() {

        var deferredObject = $.Deferred();
        // logic to acquire the auth token
        return deferredObject.promise();
    }

    $.fn.ajax = function(options) {
        return getAccessToken().then(function(token) {
            options.beforeSend = function(request) {
                request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'bearer ' + token);
            };
            return internalAjax(options);
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

The issue I'm having is that the calls to `$.getJSON` still use the original `$.ajax` and not my custom wrapper. I have tried to replace `$.fn.ajax` and `$.fn.extend`, but the original `$.ajax method is still called.

How can I replace the internal `ajax` call in jquery?

Comment: You need to change `$.fn.ajax = function(options) {` to `$.ajax = function(options) {` because `ajax` is a static method not a plugin method

Comment: That helped, also it turned out a second version of jquery was being loaded after my script, so my patch was being blown away :/